# How to redirect user after authentication from Redux action?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-router-dom

I use firebase in action Redux file to authenticate my user. But how to redirect him from login page to another?

```
import firebase from '../app/firebase/firebase.js';

export const SIGN_IN = 'SIGN_IN'
export const GET_BOOKS = 'GET_BOOKS'

export const signInState = (email, password) => dispatch => {
          firebase.auth()
         .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
         .then(() => {
           dispatch({
          type: 'SIGN_IN',
          })
        push("/home") /// here i try to redirect user
        })
        .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        alert(error);
     })
}
```

And also i have PrivateRoute in my App file. How to reach this "path"?

```
      <PrivateRoute
            path="/home"
            signedInStatus={this.props.signedInStatus}
            component={Home} />}/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just used **Connected-React-Router**

to solve my problem:

```
export const signInState = (email, password) => dispatch => {
      firebase.auth()
     .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
     .then(() => {
       dispatch({
      type: 'SIGN_IN',
      })
    dispatch(push('/home')) /// <-----that was an answer
    })
```